# how to calculate within a procedure by the result of two queries

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure called ProfitCalculation. Which takes three arguments..the procedure body is given below:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE ProfitCalculation
     (
        IN   instrument                      INT(20)    , 
        OUT  buy                             float(10,3)  ,
        OUT  sell                            float(10,3)    ,
        OUT  profit                          float(10,3)   
     )
BEGIN 

    SELECT SUM(FldLastTradeQuantity*FldPrice) as total_buy
    INTO   buy                              
    FROM   TblOrders
    WHERE  FldInstrumentID = instrument AND FldBuySell = 'b' AND FldLastTradePrice != 0 AND FldLastTradeQuantity != 0 group by FldInstrumentID;


    SELECT SUM(FldLastTradeQuantity*FldPrice) as total_buy
    INTO   sell                      
    FROM   TblOrders
    WHERE  FldInstrumentID = instrument AND FldBuySell = 's' AND FldLastTradePrice != 0 AND FldLastTradeQuantity != 0 group by FldInstrumentID; 

     profit = sell - buy;  

END
delimiter ;
```

Now I want to calculate the profit.but it returns only 1.
please give me a solution which will return the actual result.

Comment: For clarity: do you mean "it returns only 1" row, or the value 1?

Comment: value 1. I want to calculate the profit and return this profit amount.

Comment: It looks like if it's returning 1, that's because the difference between `sell` and `buy` *is* 1. Have you tried testing it with different values for `instrument` and doing the same calculations by hand (if the dataset is small enough to make that worthwhile)?

Comment: yeh i have alreaddy tested the value..the value will be 4563285.

Answer (score 1):

This procedure can be reduced to a single SQL query, which might help you with you investigation.

```
SELECT buy, sell, (sell - buy) profit FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE FldBuySell WHEN 'b' THEN FldLastTradeQuantity*FldPrice END) buy,
        SUM(CASE FldBuySell WHEN 's' THEN FldLastTradeQuantity*FldPrice END) sell
    FROM TblOrders
    WHERE FldInstrumentID = instrument AND FldLastTradePrice != 0 
      AND FldLastTradeQuantity != 0
) a;
```

Comment: I want to return the acctual profit which i m not getting from here..I have the proper query..i just want to return the actual profit..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
...
BEGIN

SELECT
  SUM(IF(FldBuySell = 'b', FldLastTradeQuantity * FldPrice, 0)) AS total_buy,
  SUM(IF(FldBuySell = 's', FldLastTradeQuantity * FldPrice, 0)) AS total_sell
  INTO buy, sell
FROM
  TblOrders
WHERE
  FldInstrumentID = instrument
  AND FldLastTradePrice != 0
  AND FldLastTradeQuantity != 0;

SET profit = sell - buy;

END
...
```

**Edit:**

Try to run this code pattern in [MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) or in another tool and check results -

```
SET @instrument = 10;
SET @buy = NULL;
SET @sell = NULL;
SET @profit = NULL;

CALL ProfitCalculation(@instrument, @buy, @sell, @profit);

SELECT @buy, @sell, @profit;
```

**Edit 2:**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE test(OUT buy FLOAT(10, 3), OUT sell FLOAT(10, 3), OUT profit FLOAT(10, 3))
BEGIN
  SELECT 10, 15 INTO buy, sell; -- variant with SELECT INTO
  SET profit = sell - buy;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

SET @buy = NULL;
SET @sell = NULL;
SET @profit = NULL;

CALL test(@buy, @sell, @profit);

SELECT @buy, @sell, @profit;

+------+-------+---------+
| @buy | @sell | @profit |
+------+-------+---------+
|   10 |    15 |       5 |
+------+-------+---------+
```

Profit is not NULL.

Comment: Where is the problem? Add 'SELECT profit;' statenent after this line 'SET profit = sell - buy;'; it will show the 'profit' value.

Comment: the calculation is not working within the procedure..it returns null..can anyone give me the proper solution..???

Comment: If one of the arguments is NULL, the result will be NULL. Check 'sell' and 'buy' values: add this line 'SELECT sell, buy;' before the 'SET profit = sell - buy;'.

Comment: CALL ProfitCalculation(205443,@profit, @buy,@sell); I call this function in this way..manually I execute the query but they are not null..

Comment: Cannot reproduce it. Have a look at the example in the answer (Edit 2). I have simplified SP to check result, 'profit' is not null.

Comment: co you tell me 1 thing please you set buy = 10;if I want to write a query like SET BUY = "select query" and same as for sell also and then calculate the profit is it acceptable??plz help me out...

Comment: Yes, of course. See my first answer; there is SELECT...INTO statement that sets two variables - 'buy' and 'sell'. The 'Edit 2' answer is also modified.

Comment: in the above procedure(extreme top) i have stored the value in buy and sell also but the profit calculation is not working..so is there any correction is needed??

Comment: What about last one (example in 'Edit 2'). It is almost the same as top variant. Does it work for you?

Comment: Very strange. Can you try on another MySQL server?

Comment: yes...I have tried in three ways but each time it returns null

Comment: the queries are ok..but I think assigning to profit variable is not correct..or or when we use INTO is not working..

Comment: SELECT @profit:= (sell - buy) FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE FldBuySell WHEN 'b' THEN FldLastTradeQuantity*FldPrice END) buy,
        SUM(CASE FldBuySell WHEN 's' THEN FldLastTradeQuantity*FldPrice END) sell
    FROM TblOrders
    WHERE FldInstrumentID = instrument AND FldLastTradePrice != 0 
      AND FldLastTradeQuantity != 0
)a; is it possible???

Comment: Oh! The problem might be in your code. There should not be two the same column and variable. You have 'sell' and 'buy' - output paramaters, and 'sell' and 'buy' as column aliases; rename them. And one more note - '@profit' and 'profit' - are not the same variables.